# Different Customer Rating options for different categories

Tags: customer, custom-options, review

Has anyone come across a way to have different customer rating options assigned to different categories/set of products?

I read an old thread from 2009 saying the feature wasn't available yet, is it  available or possible to hard code in CE1.7?

Or possibly an extension to allow me to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Tom, do you mean for reviews? So for example, in category A, you have a rating from price, but in category B, you only have a rating for quality?

Comment: I think were on the same track, so basically i have a ball as my product and one of the review ratings is leather quality on the ball, this same review rating wont be in relation to say a pair of football shorts, because the shorts arent made from leather. Does this make more sense? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible out of the box.
But if you plan to implement something like this, then don't do it at the category level. Better do it on the attribute set level, because a product can be in one or more categories (or none).
Here is an idea on how you can do it. (sorry but no code).

You can add a new column on the table `rating` called `attribute_set_id`, then add a new field in the form that adds/edits the rating option with all possible attribute sets (and an additional option with the value 0 for all attribute sets).

Then rewrite the method `Mage_Review_Block_Form::getRatings` and include an other filter based on the current product attribute set id.

And here is where my ideas stop. One last thing... you have to go through the full process of posting some ratings and make sure that all the code involved takes into consideration only the ratings available for the specific attribute set of the product.